# How could I render partial with ujs and apply javascript on new rendered html

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How could I render partial with ujs and apply javascript on new rendered html.

I have two dynamic dropdown menus on my index page.

When the first dropdown menus selected, then the second dropdown menus will be updated.

I use ujs to render second dropdown menu, which supposed to be applied on `bootstrap-select.js`.

But it didn't updated the view,  further more the view element is disappeared.

But the DOM element has been updated

[image]

## ujs

```
 $("#return_flight_dropdown").html("<%= j render(partial: 'return_flight_dropdown') %>")
```

## haml

```
#return_flight_dropdown
    .form-group
      %label.col-sm-4.control-label.form-label= t('arrival')
      .col-sm-8
        %select.selectpicker{:style => "display: none;", :name=> "to", :id=> "return_flight_opts"}
          - @available_destnations.each do |country|
            %optgroup{:label => country["_id"]}
              - options = get_cities_dropdown_opt(country)
              = options_for_select(options, "TOKYO")
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my stupid understand,

I should re-execute the js function.

$('.selectpicker').selectpicker();

after the `$("#return_flight_dropdown").html("<%= j render(partial: 'return_flight_dropdown') %>")`

Now, it works.